# How can i replace the symbols in a list?

Tags: replacement, symbols

[image]

As you can see from the picture, how can I change all the "->" symbols to "-"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [`FullForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) of a Rule

```
a -> b // FullForm

(* Rule[a, b] *)

SeedRandom[1234];

b3 = Thread[{a, b, c, d, e} -> RandomInteger[100, 5]]

(* {a -> 8, b -> 72, c -> 44, d -> 38, e -> 22} *)

b3 /. Rule[a_, b_] :> StringForm["``-``", a, b]
```

[image]

or with some space

```
b3 /. Rule[a_, b_] :> StringForm["``\[ThinSpace]-\[ThinSpace]``", a, b]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Mr Hanlon, I completely got the "-" symbol, but I faced another trouble. How can I transform the output into dataset? I tried to use Dataset function, but it showed lots of symbols different from the output.

Comment: `b3 = Thread[{a, b, c, d, e} -> RandomInteger[100, 5]]; Dataset[Association[b3]]`

Comment: Oh! I just got the same anser with Dataset function, there are lots of mess symbols.

Comment: Post a question showing data (for a small sample) and your code. Note that you cannot be be using the transformation of the `Rule` shown above since the rules must remain to form the association.

Comment: For example: c1 = {x, y, z};c2 = {1, 2, 3};c3 = Thread[c1 -> c2]      I want to get the dataset of c3, and when I just use Dataset function, it shows "->" symbol, I want to replace it with symbol  "-".

Answer (score 3):

`a->b` is a shortcut for `Rule[a,b]`. Therefore, what you have to do is to replace `Rule`by `Subtract`. E.g.:

```
SeedRandom[1]
list = Thread[{a, b, c, d, e} -> RandomInteger[100, 5]]

(* {a -> 80, b -> 14, c -> 0, d -> 67, e -> 3} *)

list /. Rule -> Subtract

(*  {-80 + a, -14 + b, c, -67 + d, -3 + e}  *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Mr Huber, but I want to get the "-" as only symbol but ont subtract.

Comment: If you want a string form: `StringReplace[ToString[list], "->" -> "-"]`

Comment: This is a good method, but I want to get a dataset in the end.